# order by with random in between in mysql

Tags: mysql

i have query like this.

```
select * from test order by rank
```

[image]

this query is displaying record order by rank. now, i have rank column range from 1 to 500000. and i want query for displaying record that up to 100000 in rank column they are display as old query and then 100000 to 400000 **they should display randomly** and then 400000 to 500000 as old query. i tried with this.

```
(SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE `rank` <= 100000 ORDER BY `rank`)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE `rank` > 100000 AND `rank` <= 400000 ORDER BY RAND())
UNION
(SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE `rank` > 400000 ORDER BY `rank`)
```

but it always display like this i want it rendom between rank column 100000 to 400000.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So you need to write two `SELECT` statements, combined by `UNION`:

```
-- Display ordered way till 100000
SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE `rank` <= 100000 ORDER BY `rank`
--- Join it.
UNION
-- Display random way after 400000
SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE `rank` > 100000 AND `rank` <= 400000 ORDER BY RAND()
-- Join it.
UNION
-- Display ordered way till 400000
SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE `rank` > 400000 ORDER BY `rank`
```

Ultimately, this would display all the records, only thing is, the first `400000` records are displayed in ascending order, and the next are random.

**Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7521d/2**

Comment: i want to display ordered way till 100000 then up to 400000 as random and then 400000 to 500000 as ordered way.

Comment: @DivyeshJesadiya This wasn't the original one. Anyway, three queries then.

Comment: @DivyeshJesadiya Updated.

Comment: i Updated problem. now they display constantly in order that second image shows.